# animating sine waves in processing

Tags: processing

how do I animate the sin lines in the following code to move along the y-axis, to somehow look more like moving water waves?

-if you take out the velocity and acceleration codes you will see what I was trying to work with

```java
float scaleVal = 6.0;
float angleInc = 0.19;

float velocity=0.0;
float acceleration=0.01;

void setup(){
  size(750,750);
  stroke(255);
}

void draw(){
  background (0);
  float angle=0.0;
  for (int offset = -10; offset < width+10; offset += 10) {
    for (int y = 1; y <= height; y += 3) {
      float x = offset + (sin(angle) * scaleVal);
      line(x, y, x, y+2);
      angle += angleInc;

      velocity += acceleration;
      y += velocity;
    }
    angle += PI;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using `sin()` to change the y position instead of x.
The x position can simply increment.

The math may be daunting, but it gets fun once you get the hang of it.
Imagine going around a circle with the radius of 1.0 in a cartesian coordinate system (0 is centre , x and y increase to the right and down and decrease towards left and top):

- Let's say you start at the top, the highest value, the length radius of your circle (1.0).
- As you decrease the angle, the x move to the left, but the y will go towards the centre( 0.0 )
- then x will increase as it gets close to the centre and y will drop to bottom of the circle (-1.0)
- then x will keep increasing until it reaches the right edge of the circle and the y value will increase and reach the vertical centre (0.0)
- finally the x will decrease until it reaches the horizontal centre and y will increase and reach back to the top of the circle (1.0)

This image explains it pretty well:
[image: sine wave from circle]

Essentially it's like a converter: you plug in an angle from 0 to 360 degrees or `TWO_PI` radians (as sin works with angles in radians) and you get back a value between -1.0 and 1.0.

If you want to draw a sine wave, you have to draw multiple points:

- the x position will increase value directly
- the y position will increase the angle, but use the result of the `sin()` function to obtain a value that goes up and down.

The last thing to do is multiple the result of the `sin()` function by a larger number to essentially scale the sine wave (from -1.0 to 1.0) to a size more appropate for the screen.

Here's a quick commented demo you can use the mouse position to play with:

```js
function setup(){
  createCanvas(640,100);
}
function draw(){
  background(255);
  
  var numberOfPoints = 1+(mouseX/2);
  //how often apart will the points be
  var widthPerPoint = width / numberOfPoints;
  //how much will the angle change from one point to another
  var anglePerPoint = TWO_PI/numberOfPoints;
  
  var waveHeight = 25;
  
  for(var i = 0; i < numberOfPoints; i++){
    var x = i *  widthPerPoint;
    var y = sin(anglePerPoint * i) * waveHeight;
    ellipse(x,50 + y,5,5);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.4/p5.min.js"></script>
```

The gist of it is this line:

```
var y = sin(anglePerPoint * i) * waveHeight;
```

which can be broken down to:

```
//increment the angle
var incrementedAngle = anglePerPoint * i;
//compute sine (-1.0,1.0)
var sine = sin(incrementedAngle);
//scale sine result
var waveY = sine * waveHeight;
```

Once you can draw a static sine wave, it's pretty easy to animate: to the angle increment at each point you add an increasing value. This increases the angle and essentially goes around the circle (`TWO_PI`) for you.

You can create your own variable to increase at your own rate or you
can easily use an increasing value based on time(`millis()`) or frame(`frameCount`) which you can scale down (divide by a large number...or better yet multiple by a small fractional number):

```js
function setup(){
  createCanvas(640,100);
}
function draw(){
  background(255);
  
  var numberOfPoints = 1+(mouseX/2);
  //how often apart will the points be
  var widthPerPoint = width / numberOfPoints;
  //how much will the angle change from one point to another
  var anglePerPoint = TWO_PI/numberOfPoints;
  
  var waveHeight = 25;
  
  for(var i = 0; i < numberOfPoints; i++){
    var x = i *  widthPerPoint;
    var y = sin(anglePerPoint * i + frameCount * 0.01) * waveHeight;
    ellipse(x,50 + y,5,5);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.4/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Hopefully the animation and simple demos above help illustrate the point.
In even simpler terms, it's a bit of an illustion: you draw points that only move up and down, but each point use an increasing angle along the circle.

Have a look at [Reuben Margolin's kinectic sculpture system demo](https://youtu.be/D2HF-1xjpP8?t=391):

[image: Reuben Margolin's kinectic sculpture system demo]

(I recommend checking out the whole PopTech talk: it's inspiring)

You should have a look at the [Processing SineWave example](https://processing.org/examples/sinewave.html) as well.

Here's a more complex encapsulating the notions in a resuable function to draw multiple waves to hint at an atmospheric perspective:

```
int numWaves = 5;
void setup(){
  size(400,400);
  noStroke();
}

void draw(){
   background(255);
   for(int i = 0 ; i < numWaves; i++){
     fill(30,120,180,map(i,0,numWaves-1,192,32));
     drawSineWave(HALF_PI,0.00025 * (i+1),50 + (10 * i),8,width,mouseY);
   }
   fill(255);
   text("drag mouse x to change number of waves",10,height-10);
}
/*
* radians   - how often does the wave cycle (larges values = more peaks)
* speed     - how fast is the wave moving
* amplitude - how high is the wave (from centre point)
* detail    - how many points are used to draw the wave (small=angled, many = smooth)
* y         - y centre of the wave
*/
void drawSineWave(float radians,float speed,float amplitude,int detail,float size,float y){
  beginShape();
  vertex(0,height);//fix to bottom
  //compute the distance between each point
  float xoffset = size / detail;
  //compute angle offset between each point
  float angleIncrement = radians / detail;
  //for each point
  for(int i = 0 ; i <= detail; i++){
    //compute x position
    float px = xoffset * i;
    //use sine function compute y
    //millis() * speed is like an ever increasing angle
    //to which we add the angle increment for each point (so the the angle changes as we traverse x
    //the result of sine is a value between -1.0 and 1.0 which we multiply to the amplitude (height of the wave)
    //finally add the y offset
    float py = y + (sin((millis() * speed) + angleIncrement * i) * amplitude);
    //add the point
    vertex(px,py);
  }
  vertex(size,height);//fix to bottom
  endShape();
}
void mouseDragged(){
  numWaves = 1+(int)mouseX/40;
}
```

Which you can also run bellow:

```js
var numWaves = 5;
function setup(){
  createCanvas(400,400);
  noStroke();
}

function draw(){
   background(255);
   for(var i = 0 ; i < numWaves; i++){
     fill(30,120,180,map(i,0,numWaves-1,192,32));
     drawSineWave(HALF_PI,0.00025 * (i+1),50 + (10 * i),8,width,mouseY);
   }
   fill(255);
   text("drag mouse x to change number of waves",10,height-10);
}
/*
* radians   - how often does the wave cycle (larges values = more peaks)
* speed     - how fast is the wave moving
* amplitude - how high is the wave (from centre point)
* detail    - how many points are used to draw the wave (small=angled, many = smooth)
* y         - y centre of the wave
*/
function drawSineWave(radians,speed,amplitude,detail,size,y){
  beginShape();
  vertex(0,height);//fix to bottom
  //compute the distance between each point
  var xoffset = size / detail;
  var angleIncrement = radians / detail;
  for(var i = 0 ; i <= detail; i++){
    var px = xoffset * i;
    var py = y + (sin((millis() * speed) + angleIncrement * i) * amplitude);
    vertex(px,py);
  }
  vertex(size,height);//fix to bottom
  endShape();
}
function mouseDragged(){
  numWaves = ceil(mouseX/40);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.4/p5.min.js"></script>
```

The only other suggestion I have, in terms of rendering, it to have play with [beginShape()](https://processing.org/reference/beginShape_.html). Rather than having to worry about where to draw each line, simply pass a bunch of points(via `vertex(x,y)`) in between `beginShape()`/`endShape()` calls and let Processing connect the dots for you.

Answer (score 2):

Stack Overflow isn't really designed for general "how do I do this" type questions. It's for more specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. That being said, I'll try to help in a general sense.

If you want to animate something going up and down, you have to modify its Y position over time.

One approach is to use the `sin()` or `cos()` functions to come up with a value that alternates between `-1` and `1`, which you can then multiply by a height and add to a center:

```java
void setup() {
  size(100, 200);
}

void draw() {
  background (0);

  float centerY = height/2;
  float waveHeight = 75;
  float input = frameCount/10.0;
  float ballY = centerY+sin(input)*waveHeight;

  ellipse(width/2, ballY, 10, 10);
}
```

Another approach is to keep track of the position and speed yourself. When the position reaches a min or max, just reverse the speed. Something like this:

```
float ballY = 100;
float ySpeed = 1;

void setup() {
  size(100, 200);
}

void draw() {
  background (0);

  ballY += ySpeed;
  if(ballY < 0 || ballY > height){
    ySpeed *= -1;
  }

  ellipse(width/2, ballY, 10, 10);
}
```

You could also use the `lerp()` function. The point is that there are a million different ways to do this. The best thing you can do is to **try something** and post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you get stuck. Good luck.

Comment: Sorry it is my first time using Stack Overflow, and I am really in my beginning stages of learning this program for school projects. I did try incorporating the velocity and acceleration codes, but all i saw was dots moving down the y-axis

Comment: Do you see the place in my code where I check the y value against the min and max, and then reverse the speed? What happened when you added that?

Comment: i tried this:

 line += ySpeed;
  if( line < 0 || line > height){
    ySpeed *= -1;

but the sin lines are not moving

Comment: @AlexanderPark That doesn't make a ton of sense. What is `line` in that code? Why don't you start with the code I provided and try to draw a single line that moves up and down as a starting point? Can you get that working?

Comment: I got stacked vertical bezier lines to go up and down (using the first code set you provided)