# I want to make a image move with sin graph, in processing

Tags: processing

```java
PImage img;
float x;

void setup() {
    img = loadImage("img.png");
}

void draw() {

}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

When you get started I recommend carefully reading the available [documentation](http://processing.org/reference/sin_.html) , [tutorial](https://processing.org/examples/sinewave.html). You can also find an exhaustive answer on using the sine function in general and applying to movement [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40291618/animating-sin-waves-in-processing/40295881#40295881)

Additionally, have a look at the [Stackoverflow Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get an idea of how the community works (and earn a badge doing so).