# What is this called and how to achieve! Visuals in processing

Tags: processing

Hey does anyone know how to achieve this effect using processing or what this is called?

I have been trying to use the wave gradient example in the processing library and implementing Perlin noise but I can not get close to the gif quality.

I know the artist used processing but can not figure out how!

[image: waves animated gif]

Link to gif:

https://giphy.com/gifs/processing-jodeus-QInYLzY33wMwM

Comment: you should post your attempt

Comment: I don't think this effect has a specific name. One of the fun things about this kind of coding is you have to take a step back and describe exactly what you're trying to do in more detail. How would you describe the effect in your own words? Then try to take that description and implement it using code. Good luck!

Comment: @ApexSnake Did you get a chance to check the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) bellow ?

Answer (score 4):

The effect is reminescent of [Op Art](https://www.tate.org.uk/art/art-terms/o/op-art) (optical illusion art): I recommend reading/learning more about this fascinating genre and artists like:

[Bridget Riley](https://www.tate.org.uk/art/artists/bridget-riley-1845)

[image: Bridget Riley 1979]

[image: Bridget Riley, Intake, 1964]

(Bridget Riley, Intake, 1964)

[image: Bridget Riley, Hesistate, 1964]

([Bridget Riley, Hesistate, 1964,
Copyright: (c) Bridget Riley 2018. All rights reserved. / Photo (c) Tate](https://www.tate.org.uk/art/artworks/riley-hesitate-t04132))

[Victor Vasarely](https://www.tate.org.uk/art/artists/victor-vasarely-2095)

[image: Zebra Couple]

(Victor Vasarely, Zebra Couple)

[image: Victor Vasarely, VegaII]

(Victor Vasarely, VegaII)

[Frank Stella](https://www.tate.org.uk/art/artists/frank-stella-1994) 
[image: Frank Stella, Untitled 1965]
(Frank Stella, Untitled 1965, Image curtesy of [Art Gallery NSW](https://www.artgallery.nsw.gov.au/exhibitions/new-contemporary-galleries/featured-artists-and-works/frank-stella/))

and more

You notice this waves are reminiscent/heavily inspired by Bridget Riley's work.

I also recommend checking out [San Charoenchai](http://www.mulletproof.com/beachhouse.html);s album visualiser for [Beach House - 7](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dyclbb_6Ycs)

[image: Beach House - 7 album music video thumbnails]

As mentioned in my comment: you should post your attempt.
Waves and perlin noise could work for sure.
There are many ways to achieve a similar look.

Here's tweaked version of [Daniel Shiffman's Noise Wave example](https://processing.org/examples/noisewave.html):

```
int numWaves = 24;

float[] yoff = new float[numWaves];        // 2nd dimension of perlin noise
float[] yoffIncrements = new float[numWaves];

void setup() {
  size(640, 360);
  noStroke();

  for(int i = 0 ; i < numWaves; i++){
    yoffIncrements[i] = map(i, 0, numWaves - 1, 0.01, 0.03);
  }
}

void draw() {
  background(0);



  float waveHeight = height / numWaves;

  for(int i = 0 ; i < numWaves; i++){

    float waveY = i * waveHeight;

    fill(i % 2 == 0 ? color(255) : color(0));
    // We are going to draw a polygon out of the wave points
    beginShape(); 

    float xoff = 0;       // Option #1: 2D Noise
    // float xoff = yoff; // Option #2: 1D Noise

    // Iterate over horizontal pixels
    for (float x = 0; x <= width + 30; x += 20) {
      // Calculate a y value according to noise, map to 
      float y = map(noise(xoff, yoff[i]), 0, 1, waveY , waveY + (waveHeight * 3)); // Option #1: 2D Noise
      // float y = map(noise(xoff), 0, 1, 200,300);    // Option #2: 1D Noise

      // Set the vertex
      vertex(x, y); 
      // Increment x dimension for noise
      xoff += 0.05;
    }
    // increment y dimension for noise
    yoff[i] += yoffIncrements[i];
    vertex(width, height);
    vertex(0, height);
    endShape(CLOSE);
  }
}
```

[image: Noise Wave modified Processing sketch]

Notice the quality of the noise wave in comparison to the image you're trying to emulate: there is a constant rhythm to it. To me that is a hint that it's using cycling sine waves changing phase and amplitude (potentially even adding waves together).

I've written an extensive answer on animating sine waves [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40291618/animating-sine-waves-in-processing/40295881#40295881)
[image: Reuben Margolin's kinectic sculpture system demo]
(Reuben Margolin's kinectic sculpture system demo)

From your question it sounds like you would be comfortable implementing a sine wave animation. It it helps, here's an example of adding two waves together:

```
void setup(){
  size(600,600);
  noStroke();
}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  // how many waves per sketch height
  int heightDivisions = 30;
  // split the sketch height into equal height sections
  float heightDivisionSize = (float)height / heightDivisions;
  // for each height division
  for(int j = 0 ; j < heightDivisions; j++){
    // use % 2 to alternate between black and white
    // see https://processing.org/reference/modulo.html and
    //     https://processing.org/reference/conditional.html for more
    fill(j % 2 == 0 ? color(255) : color(0));
    // offset drawing on Y axis
    translate(0,(j * heightDivisionSize));
    // start a wave shape
    beginShape();
    // first vertex is at the top left corner
    vertex(0,height);
    // how many horizontal (per wave) divisions ?
    int widthDivisions = 12;
    // equally space the points on the wave horizontally
    float widthDivsionSize = (float)width / widthDivisions;
    // for each point on the wave 
    for(int i = 0; i <= widthDivisions; i++){
      // calculate different phases
      // play with arithmetic operators to make interesting wave additions
      float phase1 = (frameCount * 0.01) + ((i * j) * 0.025);
      float phase2 = (frameCount * 0.05) + ((i + j) * 0.25);
      // calculate vertex x position
      float x = widthDivsionSize * i;
      // multiple sine waves
      // (can use cos() and use other ratios too
      // 150 in this case is the wave amplitude (e.g. from -150 to + 150)
      float y = ((sin(phase1) * sin(phase2) * 150));
      // draw calculated vertex
      vertex(x,y);
    }
    // last vertex is at bottom right corner
    vertex(width,height);
    // finish the shape
    endShape();
  }
}
```

The result:
[image: Additive Waves shape]

Minor note on performance: this could be implemented more efficiently using [PShape](https://processing.org/reference/createShape_.html), however I recommend playing with the maths/geometry to find the form you're after, then as a last step think of optimizing it.

My intention is not to show you how to create an exact replica, but to show there's more to Op Art than an effect and hopefully inspire you to explore other methods of achieving something similar in the hope that you will discover your own methods and outcomes: something new and of your own through fun happy accidents.

In terms of other techniques/avenues to explore:

- [displacement maps](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/W3C_SVG_0.91/htmlInkscapeHarness/filters-displace-01-f.html): [image: Displacement maps SVG filter example]
- Using an alternating black/white straight bars texture on wavy 3D geometry [image: San Charoenchai Beach House 7 album video]
- using shaders: [image: shader toy hermite curve waves surface]

Shaders are a huge topic on their own, but it's worth noting:

1. There's a very good [Processing Shader Tutorial](https://processing.org/tutorials/pshader/)
2. You might be able to explore frament shaders on [shadertoy](https://www.shadertoy.com/results?query=waves), tweak the code in browser then make slight changes so you can run them in Processing.

Here are a few quick examples:

https://www.shadertoy.com/view/Wts3DB

tweaked for black/white waves in Processing as shader-Wts3DB.frag

```
// https://www.shadertoy.com/view/Wts3DB

uniform vec2 iResolution;
uniform float iTime;

#define COUNT 6.
#define COL_BLACK vec3(23,32,38) / 255.0 

#define SF 1./min(iResolution.x,iResolution.y)
#define SS(l,s) smoothstep(SF,-SF,l-s)
#define hue(h) clamp( abs( fract(h + vec4(3,2,1,0)/3.) * 6. - 3.) -1. , 0., 1.)

// Original noise code from https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4sc3z2
#define MOD3 vec3(.1031,.11369,.13787)

vec3 hash33(vec3 p3)
{
    p3 = fract(p3 * MOD3);
    p3 += dot(p3, p3.yxz+19.19);
    return -1.0 + 2.0 * fract(vec3((p3.x + p3.y)*p3.z, (p3.x+p3.z)*p3.y, (p3.y+p3.z)*p3.x));
}

float simplex_noise(vec3 p)
{
    const float K1 = 0.333333333;
    const float K2 = 0.166666667;

    vec3 i = floor(p + (p.x + p.y + p.z) * K1);
    vec3 d0 = p - (i - (i.x + i.y + i.z) * K2);

    vec3 e = step(vec3(0.0), d0 - d0.yzx);
    vec3 i1 = e * (1.0 - e.zxy);
    vec3 i2 = 1.0 - e.zxy * (1.0 - e);

    vec3 d1 = d0 - (i1 - 1.0 * K2);
    vec3 d2 = d0 - (i2 - 2.0 * K2);
    vec3 d3 = d0 - (1.0 - 3.0 * K2);

    vec4 h = max(0.6 - vec4(dot(d0, d0), dot(d1, d1), dot(d2, d2), dot(d3, d3)), 0.0);
    vec4 n = h * h * h * h * vec4(dot(d0, hash33(i)), dot(d1, hash33(i + i1)), dot(d2, hash33(i + i2)), dot(d3, hash33(i + 1.0)));

    return dot(vec4(31.316), n);
}

void mainImage( vec4 fragColor, vec2 fragCoord )
{


}

void main(void) {
    //vec2 uv = vec2(gl_FragColor.x / iResolution.y, gl_FragColor.y / iResolution.y);
    vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / iResolution.y;
    float m = 0.;
    float t = iTime *.5;
    vec3 col;
    for(float i=COUNT; i>=0.; i-=1.){
        float edge = simplex_noise(vec3(uv * vec2(2., 0.) + vec2(0, t + i*.15), 3.))*.2 + (.95/COUNT)*i;
        float mi = SS(edge, uv.y) - SS(edge + .095, uv.y);        
        m += mi;        

        if(mi > 0.){
            col = vec3(1.0);
        }
    }           

    col = mix(COL_BLACK, col, m);

    gl_FragColor = vec4(col,1.0);

  // mainImage(gl_FragColor,gl_FragCoord);
}
```

loaded in Processing as:

```
PShader shader;

void setup(){
  size(300,300,P2D);
  noStroke();
  shader = loadShader("shader-Wts3DB.frag");
  shader.set("iResolution",(float)width, float(height));
}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  shader.set("iTime",frameCount * 0.05);
  shader(shader);
  rect(0,0,width,height);
}
```

[image: shadertoy Processing shader example 1]

https://www.shadertoy.com/view/MtsXzl

tweaked as shader-MtsXzl.frag

```
//https://www.shadertoy.com/view/MtsXzl
#define SHOW_GRID 1

const float c_scale = 0.5;
const float c_rate = 2.0;

#define FLT_MAX 3.402823466e+38

uniform vec3 iMouse;
uniform vec2 iResolution;
uniform float iTime;

//=======================================================================================
float CubicHermite (float A, float B, float C, float D, float t)
{
    float t2 = t*t;
    float t3 = t*t*t;
    float a = -A/2.0 + (3.0*B)/2.0 - (3.0*C)/2.0 + D/2.0;
    float b = A - (5.0*B)/2.0 + 2.0*C - D / 2.0;
    float c = -A/2.0 + C/2.0;
    float d = B;

    return a*t3 + b*t2 + c*t + d;
}

//=======================================================================================
float hash(float n) {
    return fract(sin(n) * 43758.5453123);
}

//=======================================================================================
float GetHeightAtTile(vec2 T)
{
    float rate = hash(hash(T.x) * hash(T.y))*0.5+0.5;

    return (sin(iTime*rate*c_rate) * 0.5 + 0.5) * c_scale;
}

//=======================================================================================
float HeightAtPos(vec2 P)
{
    vec2 tile = floor(P);

    P = fract(P);

    float CP0X = CubicHermite(
        GetHeightAtTile(tile + vec2(-1.0,-1.0)),
        GetHeightAtTile(tile + vec2(-1.0, 0.0)),
        GetHeightAtTile(tile + vec2(-1.0, 1.0)),
        GetHeightAtTile(tile + vec2(-1.0, 2.0)),
        P.y
    );

    float CP1X = CubicHermite(
        GetHeightAtTile(tile + vec2( 0.0,-1.0)),
        GetHeightAtTile(tile + vec2( 0.0, 0.0)),
        GetHeightAtTile(tile + vec2( 0.0, 1.0)),
        GetHeightAtTile(tile + vec2( 0.0, 2.0)),
        P.y
    );    

    float CP2X = CubicHermite(
        GetHeightAtTile(tile + vec2( 1.0,-1.0)),
        GetHeightAtTile(tile + vec2( 1.0, 0.0)),
        GetHeightAtTile(tile + vec2( 1.0, 1.0)),
        GetHeightAtTile(tile + vec2( 1.0, 2.0)),
        P.y
    );        

    float CP3X = CubicHermite(
        GetHeightAtTile(tile + vec2( 2.0,-1.0)),
        GetHeightAtTile(tile + vec2( 2.0, 0.0)),
        GetHeightAtTile(tile + vec2( 2.0, 1.0)),
        GetHeightAtTile(tile + vec2( 2.0, 2.0)),
        P.y
    );

    return CubicHermite(CP0X, CP1X, CP2X, CP3X, P.x);
}

//=======================================================================================
vec3 NormalAtPos( vec2 p )
{
    float eps = 0.01;
    vec3 n = vec3( HeightAtPos(vec2(p.x-eps,p.y)) - HeightAtPos(vec2(p.x+eps,p.y)),
                         2.0*eps,
                         HeightAtPos(vec2(p.x,p.y-eps)) - HeightAtPos(vec2(p.x,p.y+eps)));
    return normalize( n );
}

//=======================================================================================
float RayIntersectSphere (vec4 sphere, in vec3 rayPos, in vec3 rayDir)
{
    //get the vector from the center of this circle to where the ray begins.
    vec3 m = rayPos - sphere.xyz;

    //get the dot product of the above vector and the ray's vector
    float b = dot(m, rayDir);

    float c = dot(m, m) - sphere.w * sphere.w;

    //exit if r's origin outside s (c > 0) and r pointing away from s (b > 0)
    if(c > 0.0 && b > 0.0)
        return -1.0;

    //calculate discriminant
    float discr = b * b - c;

    //a negative discriminant corresponds to ray missing sphere
    if(discr < 0.0)
        return -1.0;

    //ray now found to intersect sphere, compute smallest t value of intersection
    float collisionTime = -b - sqrt(discr);

    //if t is negative, ray started inside sphere so clamp t to zero and remember that we hit from the inside
    if(collisionTime < 0.0)
        collisionTime = -b + sqrt(discr);

    return collisionTime;
}

//=======================================================================================
vec3 DiffuseColor (in vec3 pos)
{
    #if SHOW_GRID
    pos = mod(floor(pos),2.0);
    return vec3(mod(pos.x, 2.0) < 1.0 ? 1.0 : 0.0);
    #else
    return vec3(0.1, 0.8, 0.9);
    #endif
}

//=======================================================================================
vec3 ShadePoint (in vec3 pos, in vec3 rayDir, float time, bool fromUnderneath)
{
    vec3 diffuseColor = DiffuseColor(pos);
    vec3 reverseLightDir = normalize(vec3(1.0,1.0,-1.0));
    vec3 lightColor = vec3(1.0);    
    vec3 ambientColor = vec3(0.05);

    vec3 normal = NormalAtPos(pos.xz);
    normal *= fromUnderneath ? -1.0 : 1.0;

    // diffuse
    vec3 color = diffuseColor;
    float dp = dot(normal, reverseLightDir);
    if(dp > 0.0)
        color += (diffuseColor * lightColor);

    return color;
}

//=======================================================================================
vec3 HandleRay (in vec3 rayPos, in vec3 rayDir, in vec3 pixelColor, out float hitTime)
{
    float time = 0.0;
    float lastHeight = 0.0;
    float lastY = 0.0;
    float height;
    bool hitFound = false;
    hitTime = FLT_MAX;
    bool fromUnderneath = false;

    vec2 timeMinMax = vec2(0.0, 20.0);

    time = timeMinMax.x;

    const int c_numIters = 100;
    float deltaT = (timeMinMax.y - timeMinMax.x) / float(c_numIters);

    vec3 pos = rayPos + rayDir * time;
    float firstSign = sign(pos.y - HeightAtPos(pos.xz));

    for (int index = 0; index < c_numIters; ++index)
    {       
        pos = rayPos + rayDir * time;

        height = HeightAtPos(pos.xz);

        if (sign(pos.y - height) * firstSign < 0.0)
        {
            fromUnderneath = firstSign < 0.0; 
            hitFound = true;
            break;
        }

        time += deltaT;     
        lastHeight = height;
        lastY = pos.y;
    }


    if (hitFound) {
        time = time - deltaT + deltaT*(lastHeight-lastY)/(pos.y-lastY-height+lastHeight);
        pos = rayPos + rayDir * time;
        pixelColor = ShadePoint(pos, rayDir, time, fromUnderneath);
        hitTime = time;
    }

    return pixelColor;
}

//=======================================================================================
void main()
{      
    // scrolling camera
    vec3 cameraOffset = vec3(iTime, 0.5, iTime);

    //----- camera
    vec2 mouse = iMouse.xy / iResolution.xy;

    vec3 cameraAt   = vec3(0.5,0.5,0.5) + cameraOffset;

    float angleX = iMouse.z > 0.0 ? 6.28 * mouse.x : 3.14 + iTime * 0.25;
    float angleY = iMouse.z > 0.0 ? (mouse.y * 6.28) - 0.4 : 0.5;
    vec3 cameraPos  = (vec3(sin(angleX)*cos(angleY), sin(angleY), cos(angleX)*cos(angleY))) * 5.0;

 //    float angleX = 0.8;
 //    float angleY = 0.8;
 //    vec3 cameraPos = vec3(0.0,0.0,0.0);
    cameraPos += vec3(0.5,0.5,0.5) + cameraOffset;

    vec3 cameraFwd  = normalize(cameraAt - cameraPos);
    vec3 cameraLeft  = normalize(cross(normalize(cameraAt - cameraPos), vec3(0.0,sign(cos(angleY)),0.0)));
    vec3 cameraUp   = normalize(cross(cameraLeft, cameraFwd));

    float cameraViewWidth   = 6.0;
    float cameraViewHeight  = cameraViewWidth * iResolution.y / iResolution.x;
    float cameraDistance    = 6.0;  // intuitively backwards!


    // Objects
    vec2 rawPercent = (gl_FragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy);
    vec2 percent = rawPercent - vec2(0.5,0.5);

    vec3 rayTarget = (cameraFwd * vec3(cameraDistance,cameraDistance,cameraDistance))
                   - (cameraLeft * percent.x * cameraViewWidth)
                   + (cameraUp * percent.y * cameraViewHeight);
    vec3 rayDir = normalize(rayTarget);


    float hitTime = FLT_MAX;
    vec3 pixelColor = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    pixelColor = HandleRay(cameraPos, rayDir, pixelColor, hitTime);


    gl_FragColor = vec4(clamp(pixelColor,0.0,1.0), 1.0);
}
```

and the mouse interactive Processing sketch:

```
PShader shader;

void setup(){
  size(300,300,P2D);
  noStroke();
  shader = loadShader("shader-MtsXzl.frag");
  shader.set("iResolution",(float)width, float(height));
}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  shader.set("iTime",frameCount * 0.05);
  shader.set("iMouse",(float)mouseX , (float)mouseY, mousePressed ? 1.0 : 0.0);
  shader(shader);
  rect(0,0,width,height);
}
```

[image: shadertoy Processing shader example 1]

Shadertoy is great way to play/learn: have fun !

**Update**
Here's a quick test tweaking [Daniel Shiffman's 3D Terrain Generation example](https://thecodingtrain.com/CodingChallenges/011-perlinnoiseterrain.html) to add a stripped texture and basic sine waves instead of perlin noise:

[image: waves motion surface with stripped texture]

```
// Daniel Shiffman
// http://codingtra.in
// http://patreon.com/codingtrain
// Code for: https://youtu.be/IKB1hWWedMk

int cols, rows;
int scl = 20;
int w = 2000;
int h = 1600;

float flying = 0;

float[][] terrain;

PImage texture;

void setup() {
  size(600, 600, P3D);
  textureMode(NORMAL);
  noStroke();

  cols = w / scl;
  rows = h/ scl;
  terrain = new float[cols][rows];

  texture = getBarsTexture(512,512,96);
}


void draw() {

  flying -= 0.1;

  float yoff = flying;
  for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
    float xoff = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < cols; x++) {
      //terrain[x][y] = map(noise(xoff, yoff), 0, 1, -100, 100);
      terrain[x][y] = map(sin(xoff) * sin(yoff), 0, 1, -60, 60);
      xoff += 0.2;
    }
    yoff += 0.2;
  }



  background(0);

  translate(width/2, height/2+50);
  rotateX(PI/9);
  translate(-w/2, -h/2);
  for (int y = 0; y < rows-1; y++) {
    beginShape(TRIANGLE_STRIP);
    texture(texture);
    for (int x = 0; x < cols; x++) {

      float u0 = map(x,0,cols-1,0.0,1.0);
      float u1 = map(x+1,0,cols-1,0.0,1.0);
      float v0 = map(y,0,rows-1,0.0,1.0);
      float v1 = map(y+1,0,rows-1,0.0,1.0);

      vertex(x*scl, y*scl, terrain[x][y], u0, v0);
      vertex(x*scl, (y+1)*scl, terrain[x][y+1], u1, v1);
    }
    endShape();
  }

}

PGraphics getBarsTexture(int textureWidth, int textureHeight, int numBars){
  PGraphics texture = createGraphics(textureWidth, textureHeight);
  int moduleSide = textureWidth / numBars;

  texture.beginDraw();
  texture.background(0);
  texture.noStroke();
  for(int i = 0; i < numBars; i+= 2){
    texture.rect(0, i * moduleSide, textureWidth, moduleSide);
  }
  texture.endDraw();

  return texture;
}
```