# curveVertex in Processing

Tags: processing, curve, vertex

[image: dunes]So, I'm creating a curveVertex that it's animated. It's a line, basically, with amplitude. The image is a rough sketch of what I want to achieve
Now I want to fill it, creating the idea of a dune or mountain, but when I do it, an imaginary line is created between the first and last point and does not fill it the right way

```
int count = 50;
float time;
float amp;

// line param
float spacing = 45;

class dunes {

  void drawDunes() {

    stroke(211, 132, 52);
    strokeWeight(2);
    noFill();

    frameRate(24);
    //translate(-width, -height);
    //scale(3);

    time += .03;
    amp = map(width, 0, width, 5, 15);

    pushMatrix();
    translate(width/2 - count*spacing/2, 0);

    beginShape();
    curveVertex(0, height/2);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      float x = i * spacing;
      float y = height-250 + (sin(x + time) * amp + random(-.4, .4));

      curveVertex(x, y);
    }
    curveVertex(count*spacing, height/2);
    endShape();
    popMatrix();
  }
}
```

How do I fill a curveVertex that it's like a sinusoidal wave?

Comment: Technical note: a curveVertex "is nothing" in the sense that it's an instruction used to build out a path, so you have a "path" that is animated, built up using curveVertex instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your image: add some regular vertices and draw "rectangles with a wavy top edge":

[image]

That is, set up all the corners with regular `vertex()`, then add the curvy wave using `curveVertex`, and then use `endShape(CLOSE)` to create a closed shape layer. Do that for all your shapes and then draw them ordered "back to front".

Comment: I added an image to my original question to try to explain my idea better. Hopefully it is more clear now :)

Comment: So use curveVertex _and_ vertex. You don't want "a wave that then gets filled", keep it simple: you want to layer closed shapes that are basically rectangles with a single edge (the top one) consisting of curveVertices and the other ones are just straight lines.

Comment: so, I just need to add a vertex before the curveVertex? 

````beginShape();

    curveVertex(0, height/2);
    vertex(width, height);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      float x = i * spacing;
      float y = height-250 + (sin(x + time) * amp + random(-.4, .4));


      curveVertex(x, y);
    }
    curveVertex(count*spacing, height/2);
    curveVertex(count*spacing, height/3);
    endShape(CLOSE);
    popMatrix();```

Maybe I'm putting in the wrong place, because it's not working

Comment: Please don't drop an entire code block in a comment, comments don't have code formatting. But yes, you just add the corners using vertex. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Mike's answer is correct (+1): you'd need vertex points to define the boundaries of the shape.

I'd like to add a few notes specific to your code:

- variables relevant to the `dunes` class should be encapsulated. For example `count, time, amp, spacing` should be inside `class dunes{}`, otherwise there are global variables which means that if you were to have multiple `dunes` instances they would appear very similar (animate in sync, etc.)
- It might make it easier on the long run to use Java naming conventions, for example using a title case for the class name and plural if it's a collection(e.g. array/arraylist/etc.): `class Dune{}` instead of `class dunes{}` (this would make the code less confusing when you'd handle an array of `Dune` instances).
- you can take advantage of class properties to make each `Dune` instance slightly different.

Here's an example based on your code using the notes above:

```java
Dune[] dunes = {new Dune(), new Dune(), new Dune()};

void setup(){
  size(300, 300);
  frameRate(24);
  noStroke();
  
  for(int i = 0 ; i < dunes.length; i++){
    // reverse map alpha (1st = background dune = more alpha))
    dunes[i].alpha = map(i, 0, dunes.length - 1, 64, 32);
    // map y
    dunes[i].y = map(i, 0, dunes.length - 1, -30, 30);
    // set bounds, increasing height so offset dune is still drawn til the bottom of the sketch
    dunes[i].width = width;
    dunes[i].height = height + 30;
    // use indepenedent time increments for each dune
    dunes[i].timeIncrement = map(i, 0, dunes.length - 1, .03, .09);
  }
}

void draw(){
  background(#E3CCB7);
  fill(211, 132, 52);
  for(int i = 0 ; i < dunes.length; i++){
    dunes[i].draw();
  }
}



class Dune {

  float alpha = 32;
  float x, y;
  float timeIncrement = .03;
  float width;
  float height;
  
  int count = 50;
  float time = 0;
  float amp = 9;
  
  // line param
  float spacing = 45;

  
  void draw() {

    fill(211, 132, 52, alpha);
    

    time += timeIncrement;
    amp = map(width, 0, width, 5, 15);

    pushMatrix();
    translate(x, y);
    beginShape();
    // mid-left point
    vertex(0, height/2);
    // upper curveVertex points
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      float x = i * spacing;
      float y = height-250 + (sin(x + time) * amp + random(-.4, .4));

      curveVertex(x, y);
    }
    // mid-right point
    vertex(count*spacing, height/2);
    // bottom-right point
    vertex(width, height);
    // bottom-left point
    vertex(0, height);
    endShape();
    popMatrix();
  }
}
```

You've already understood the essential parts for drawing curves using sine waves. (If it helps, I've posted a more basic breakdown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40291618/animating-sine-waves-in-processing/40295881#40295881))

Comment: It worked perfectly! And now I understood vertex() and curveVertex().
Thank you so much :)