# A circle that has a specific percentage amount of fill

Tags: processing

I would like to create a circle that is filled to a certain percentage like so:

[image: a white circle with a thick black outline with a blue section at the bottom of the section, also delineated with a thick outline]

and this:
[image: a bottom to top preloader masked by a circle with 2 backgrounds: light blue and dark blue. the motion appears as (sine) waves giving the impression of water levels rising. additionally the loaded percentage is displayed as white text]

I'm using Processing Java.

My attempt is using the [`arc()`](https://processing.org/reference/arc_.html) function however I have a hard time determining how I should calculate the values for `angle1` and `angle2`:

```java
        percentageRemaining = 0.25;
        angle1 = ????
        angle2 = ????
        noStroke();
        fill(35);
        arc(100, 100, 200, 200, angle1, angle2, CHORD);
```

I did try some fixes with no luck thus far.

Comment: Hi and welcome ! The first image looks simpler, with no wave motion, while the seconds seems to have two animated sine waves. Regarding the first image, Sash's answer bellow is great (+1). You'll need to swap `let startTime` to `int startTime; and `let circleRadius` to `int circleRadius` as well as `function` for `void` to run in Processing java, but it's a great start! If you really want animated sine waves you can check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40291618/animating-sine-waves-in-processing/40295881#40295881). You may need `mask()` and `PGraphics`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have Processing on my computer, so I tried with [editor.p5js.org](https://editor.p5js.org/) (Javascript version of Processing). It should be pretty easy to convert:

```
let startTime;
let circleRadius = 200;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(800, 600);
  startTime = millis();
}

function draw() {
  background(255);

  let elapsedTime = (millis() - startTime) / 500.0;
  let percentage = min(elapsedTime / 10.0, 1);
  let fillHeight = circleRadius * 2 * percentage;

  // Draw blue rectangle fill, from bottom to top
  fill(0, 0, 255);
  noStroke();
  rect(width / 2 - circleRadius, height / 2 + circleRadius - fillHeight, circleRadius * 2, fillHeight);

  // White overlay to mask outside of circle
  fill(255);
  noStroke();
  beginShape();
  for (let angle = 0; angle < TWO_PI; angle += 0.01) {
    let x = width / 2 + circleRadius * cos(angle);
    let y = height / 2 + circleRadius * sin(angle);
    vertex(x, y);
  }
  for (let angle = TWO_PI; angle > 0; angle -= 0.01) {
    let x = width / 2 + (circleRadius + 100) * cos(angle);
    let y = height / 2 + (circleRadius + 100) * sin(angle);
    vertex(x, y);
  }
  endShape(CLOSE);

  // Draw outer circle
  noFill();
  stroke(0);
  strokeWeight(5);
  ellipse(width / 2, height / 2, circleRadius * 2);

  // Draw percentage text
  let textY = height / 2;
  let percentText = nf(percentage * 100, 0, 2) + "%";
  
  fill(textY < height / 2 + circleRadius - fillHeight ? 0 : 255);
  noStroke(); // Remove outline from text
  
  textSize(32);
  textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
  text(percentText, width / 2, textY);
}
```

**Output:**

[image: blue_circle_gif_2]

Not perfect... But should be a reasonable start!